# Understanding Liouville numbers and irrationality measure

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers, irrationality-measure, liouville-numbers

Every number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has an associated irrationality measure $\mu(x)$. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the algebraic numbers and let $x_\mathbb{Q} \in \mathbb{Q}, x_{\mathbb{A}\setminus\mathbb{Q}} \in \mathbb{A}\setminus\mathbb{Q}, x_T \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{A}$, and $x_L$ a Liouville number. Then

$\mu(x_\mathbb{Q}) = 1$,
$\mu(x_{\mathbb{A}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}) = 2$,
$\mu(x_T) \geq 2$, and
$\mu(x_L) = \infty$.

So any number $x_T$ with $\mu(x_T) > 2$, due to the definition of the irrationality measure, can be better approximated by rationals than any algebraic number (because $\mu(x_{\mathbb{A}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}) = 2$, but $\mu(x_T) > 2$ is better).

Now I don't understand this sentence on Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number ):

> They [Liouville numbers] are precisely those transcendental
> numbers that can be more closely approximated by rational numbers than
> any algebraic irrational number.

But what about those numbers with $2 < \mu(x_T) < \infty$? They are not Liouville numbers, but still they can be better approximated by rationals (i.e. they have larger irrationality measure) than any algebraic number.

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer having larger irrationality measure is being better approximatable by rationals

Comment: The wikipedia statement does not mention the irrationality measure. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer so what do you think that "more closely" means on wikipedia in the quoted text?

Comment: It seems to me that the Wikipedia statement should not have used "precisely those" followed by wording that is only intended to give a rough idea. Better would be: *They are transcendental numbers that can be especially well approximated by rational numbers, better than any algebraic irrational number and even better than many transcendental numbers.* Note that in using ["well approximated"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22well+approximated%22+%22numbers%22&filter=0) I'm also including a common phrase often used in the literature, which helps readers in searching for more information.

Comment: Incidentally, my comment to [Exponentially well-approximable numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/395313/15780) about [ultra-Liouville numbers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ultra-Liouville+number%22&filter=0) might be of interest. Rather than lumping all the $\mu = \infty$ numbers together (the Liouville numbers), one can further classify certain Liouville numbers by using stronger types of irrationality measures.